# Differentiability at the origin of Norm

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, frechet-derivative

For $\alpha > 1$, show that $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, given by
$$f(x)=\rVert x\rVert^\alpha$$
is differentiable at the origin.

**What I did:**

What is necessary is to find a linear transformation such that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)-Th}{\rVert h \rVert}=0$. $f(h)-f(0) = \rVert h\rVert ^\alpha$. So, because $\alpha>1$, I guess that T=0 so that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)-Th}{\rVert h \rVert}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\rVert h\rVert ^\alpha}{\rVert h \rVert}=\lim_{h\to 0}\rVert h\rVert^{\alpha-1}=0$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However, note that $f\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: It is correct. You could also do that without guessing by calculating the partial derivatives. (which is of course not enough to prove differentiability, but that would give you the only linear transformation that might be the derivative)

Comment: @Mark if the partial derivatives are continuous this is enough. Moreover how taking the partial derivatives gives you information here about the differential since we don't know the norm he is using ?

Comment: @Thinking, if they are continuous then yes, it is enough. Not so easy to prove they are continuous though. And yes, you are right that OP didn't write what norm it is. I supposed it is the Euclidean norm.